# Manipulating power key in android studio

Tags: java, android, mobile, background-service

I am trying to make a safety app. So the idea is, if my mobile is in a locked state, no one should be able to turn it off. Such that, if someone presses the power button for a long time, it immediately returns to the lock screen right after the button is released. A sample of my idea is ATMT app.